# All UITableCells disappear when tapping on UITableView in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, uistoryboard

I am having a problem with my UITableView in iOS7. Initially, the data loads in just fine, and I get output in my console that proves that the cells are speaking to the data source correctly, **but as soon as I tap anywhere on the table, the cells disappear and the table goes blank**. The height of the cells in the empty UITableView seem to be honoring the height my custom prototype cell (410px), but all the data in the cells vanish, and the empty table view acts like it only has one cell in it (like its default state before it gets hooked up to the delegate).

I am using Storyboards for this app.

To get a little context, this app is similar to the iphone Instagram app, and I am using this application as way to learn iOS 7 development. I have been banging my head up against a wall trying to solve this issue, and I can't find any online resources that can help me solve this, so I wanted to ask all the smart peeps on Stack Overflow.

I have prepared a graphic that helps you see the problem

[image: a graphic that helps demonstrate the problem]
[higher resolution version here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysNMx.jpg)

Here is my TableViewController code:

```
@interface PA_PhotoTableViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *photos;

@end



@implementation PA_PhotoTableViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.photos = [[PA_PhotoStore sharedPhotoStore] allPhotos];
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[[PA_PhotoStore sharedPhotoStore] allPhotos] count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    PA_PhotoCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PhotoCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


    PA_Photo *photo = (self.photos)[indexPath.row];

    cell.photoTitle.text = photo.title;
    cell.photoOwnerName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", photo.owner];
    cell.photoLikes.text = @"99";

    // Photo Image URL
    NSURL *photoImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:photo.image_full_url];
    [cell.photoImage sd_setImageWithURL:photoImageURL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lightGraySpinningLoader.gif"]];

    // Photo Owner Image
    [cell.photoOwnerImage sd_setImageWithURL:photoImageURL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lightGraySpinningLoader.gif"]];


    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // This code never gets called when I try to tap on a cell
    NSLog(@"A row was selected");
}


- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"dealloc called in PA_PhotoTableViewController");
}
```

and here is the custom cell code PA_PhotoCell (consolidated .h & .m files):

```
@interface PA_PhotoCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *photoImage;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *photoTitle;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *photoOwnerName;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *photoOwnerImage;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *photoLikes;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *photoTimestamp;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *photoComments;

@end



@implementation PA_PhotoCell

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    NSLog(@"in set selected");
}


-(void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted {
    NSLog(@"in set highlighted");
}
```

You can see a few `NSLog()` calls to help me see if anything is getting called.

Where am I going wrong? The end goal is to click on one of the TableViewCell instances and launch a UINavigationController, I know how to do that, but I can't move on to that step until I figure out why my UITableView won't scroll, and why it disappears when I click on it!

***EDIT:*** After much testing, debugging and experimentation, I have been able to conclude that the problem is actually not with the UITableView at all, and it is, in fact,  a problem with how the UITableView is being loaded into its parent view. I still haven't found a solution to my problem, but I am getting closer to finding the cause. Here is what I have discovered:

First, when any of the UIButtons at the bottom of the screen are tapped (see photo reference), it loads the relevant instance of UIViewController into a UIView called placeholderView. When I run my problematic UITableView OUTSIDE of this UIView (where the UITableViewController is acting on its own, not embedded within another UIView) then the table works perfectly, it scrolls, it revives click events, and so on. So as soon as I load the UITableView into the UIView, the UITableView becomes unresponsive (it doesn't scroll or receive tap events) and any attempt to interact with it, the UITableView goes completely blank. My debugging session concludes that the NSArray *photos never gets reset to nil, or manipulated in anyway, the table just goes blank.

So does anyone have any ideas on what would cause a UITableView to do this when being loaded into a generic UIView? All the other views that get loaded into this generic UIView are responsive, and behave as expected. Its just this UITableView that is giving me problems.

If you review the graphic I attached to this post (above), you will see that I am using what appears to be a UITabBarView, but it is, in fact, just a generic view with UIButtons inside. The reason I decided to craft my own "UITabBarView look-alike" instead of using the ready-made UITAbBarView class was because I wanted to give custom functionality to the "menu" button on the bottom left (I want a nice UIView to slide in from the left, and stop about 60 pixels from the right of the screen when the "menu" button is tapped, and I can't figure out how to customize the behavior of the UITabBarView, so I opted for this approach.

Here is the code that is actually loading the UITableViewController into the subview (via a CustomStoryboardSegway):

```
// PA_HomeViewCustomStoryboardSegue.m

#import "PA_HomeViewCustomStoryboardSegue.h"
#import "PA_HomeViewController.h"

@implementation PA_HomeViewCustomStoryboardSegue

// to create a custom segue, you have to override the perform method
-(void)perform {

    // get the source and destination view controllers
    PA_HomeViewController *segueSourceController = (PA_HomeViewController *)[self sourceViewController];
    UIViewController *destinationController = (UIViewController *)[self destinationViewController];

    for (UIView *view in segueSourceController.placeholderView.subviews){
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }

    segueSourceController.currentViewController = destinationController;
    [segueSourceController.placeholderView addSubview:destinationController.view];

}

@end
```

and here is the header file for my PA_HomeViewController (the view the contains the "placeholderView" which is the target view that loads the various UIViewControllers after the user has tapped the UIButtons at the bottom of the view (similar to a TabBarView) :

```
@interface PA_HomeViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *placeholderView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) UIViewController *currentViewController;

@end
```

I am hoping that I am just missing something obvious in the way that I am loading the UITableView into the placeholderView, and something in there is causing the UITableView to go completely blank.

Comment: Did you register your cell PA_PhotoCell with the table view?

Comment: That's what I was wondering, but if he didn't he'd get a runtime exception.

Comment: A couple of questions.  It sounds like the tableview datasource is set but it's acting like the delegate isn't set.  Also, It's acting like after a cell is tapped, the photos NSArray is getting clobbered somehow.

Comment: Your `initWithStyle` doesn't look right. It should call `[super initWithStyle:style]`

Comment: Is DataSource and Delegate set ? did you try to call [tableView reloadData] ?

Comment: Neither of your init methods are implemented correctly, and in any case, they're not doing anything, so you should delete them.

Comment: @Colin, @Mike - Yes, I registered my PA_PhotoCell with the tableview in the storyboard using the Custom Class section of the Identity Inspector. Also, the PA_PhotoCell class gets wired up to the TableView in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: I removed the init methods that weren't doing anything, or were incorrect, thanks for pointing that out (Paulw11 and rdelmar).

Comment: @turboc, I doubled checked, and the PA_PhotoTableViewController is set as the dataSource and the delegate in the "Referencing Outlets" section, but you could be right about the photos NSArray, I will look into that now and report back.

Comment: Probably not a fix, but I would have `numberOfRowsInSection:` return the count of `self.photos` since that's what you're using to populate cells.  (I know it's a copy, but....)  Before doing that, though, try logging the value you're returning for the number of rows to see if it makes sense.

Comment: After doing lots of testing/debugging based on everyone's feedback, I have made some big edits to this post, based on what was discovered. The problem is still happening, only now I have ruled out a problem with the UITableView itself, and concluded that the problem lies within the way the UITableView is being loaded into it's parent container, because when I run the UITableView outside of a parent container, it works perfectly, but when I run the UITAbleView after it has been embedded inside a generic UIView (the "placeholder" view mentioned in my edits), the table vanishes after tapping.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you display the `UITableView` in a different view, you must always make sure that the view controller which "hosts" the `UITableView` has a strong reference to its controller. In your case, the data source for the `UITableView` seems to be deallocated after adding the `UITableView` as subview.

Changing the currentViewController property from `weak` to `strong` should fix your problem.

Comment: Wow. After days of banging my head against the wall...all I had to do was change the reference from `weak` to `strong`. After I followed your advice, things worked perfectly! Thanks! This means I will have to really study how memory management works so I can avoid silly problems like this in the future. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Glad it helped :) You would generally mark all properties of object type as strong, except IBOutlets, delegates and few other special cases.

Comment: In swift you need to declare viewcontroller object globally that would result in Strong, in case if you declare locally it results in keep disappearing the cells.

Comment: for me: I'm using my git: https://github.com/davidseek/SLPagingViewSwift-Swift-3-Tinder-Twitter and the stupid cells disappeared after clicking them. drove me crazy. then i came across the problem that the dataSource may be a problem, but i had no idea how to set the controller with a strong reference, since it's just instantiated... but your comment - setting it as global object - did the trick... so thank you and good night ;)

Answer (score 2):

In swift you need to declare viewcontroller object globally that would result in Strong, in case if you declare locally it results in keep disappearing the cells.

e.g.

```
var refineViewController : RefineViewController?
```

then you can access that controller using below code that would not result in disappearing cells.

```
func showRefineView(isFindHomeTab isFindHomeTab : Bool){


    refineViewController =   RefineViewController(nibName: String(BaseGroupedTableVC),bundle : nil)

    refineViewController!.refineSearchDelegate = self

    refineViewController!.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, -490, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations:
        {

            self.refineViewController!.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)
            self.refineViewController!.isFindHomeTab = isFindHomeTab

        }, completion: nil)

        self.view.addSubview(refineViewController!.view)

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the exact same problem.  The issue was that I was using a custom datasource class (called tableVCDataSource), and was setting the tableView's dataSource incorrectly in the ViewController class.  I was doing:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    mainTableView.dataSource = TableVCDataSource()
}
```

when I should have been doing:

```
fileprivate var tableVCDataSource: TableVCDataSource?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    tableVCDataSource = TableVCDataSource()
    mainTableView.dataSource = tableVCDataSource
}
```

This solved my issue.