# UIScrollView with many UITableVIew inside UIViewControllers disappear UITableViewCell's on tap

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I need to make UIScrollView with UIViewController's inside, every UIViewController has UITableview.

When I tap to UITableview, all UITableViewCells are disappear.

How I initialise UIViewController inside UIScrollView?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

int width = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < [self.dishes count]; i++) {

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Order" bundle:nil];
    OneDayDishViewController *myVC = (OneDayDishViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OneDayDishViewController"];
    myVC.dishes = self.dishes[i];
    myVC.menuTitle = self.menuTitle;

    [self.scrollView addSubview:myVC.view];
    width += 375;
}

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width,0);
```

}

After looking for in google & stack overflow I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25560327/all-uitablecells-disappear-when-tapping-on-uitableview-in-ios-7)

So I done something like this

in my .h file (where I have UIScrollView):

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) OneDayDishViewController *myVC;
```

Than in my .m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

int width = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < [self.dishes count]; i++) {

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Order" bundle:nil];
    self.myVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OneDayDishViewController"];
    self.myVC.dishes = self.dishes[i];
    self.myVC.menuTitle = self.menuTitle;

    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.myVC.view];
    width += 375;
}

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width,0);
```

}

Now I also have N elements in my scrollview, if I tap the last element - it's work fine, if I tap any other element - the problem is the same.

So what I do wrong or how I can create (strong) proper dynamically and is it good practice?

Thanks

UPDT:
Thank you @CZ54
my solution is add childviewcontroller so do

```
         [self addChildViewController:myVC];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:myVC.view];
    [myVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

instead of

```
[self.scrollView addSubview:myVC.view];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the subview is not enough.

You have to add the entire controller using 
`addChildViewController:` ( from https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621394-addchildviewcontroller )

And you have to retain every instance you are adding.

Change

`@property (strong, nonatomic) OneDayDishViewController *myVC;`

into

`@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray<OneDayDishViewController*> *myVC;`

Comment: @property (strong, nonatomic) Array<OneDayDishViewController*> *myVC;
I saw for the first time definition like this (may be because I am junior) is It objective-c syntaxes?

Comment: @BorisKuzevanov indeed

Comment: Thank you, I found the solution with your help
`         [self addChildViewController:myVC];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:myVC.view];
        [myVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];`
instead of only `[self.scrollView addSubview:myVC.view];`